# Remove element from an array in python3

Tags: python, list, python-3.5

In Python3, how can I remove an array element? 
I have tried, like this:

```
In [1]: arr=[13,14,67,23,9]

In [2]: arr.remove(2)
```

I want to remove the 3rd position element but it's throwing this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-67be49ced0b0> in <module>()
----> 1 arr.remove(2)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `del` in case you want to remove an item by index:

```
>>> arr=[13,14,67,23,9]
>>> del arr[2]
>>> arr
[13, 14, 23, 9]
```

Because `remove` just removes the **first** item with that value, or if it doesn't exist in the list throws the exception you got:

```
>>> arr=[13,14,67,23,9]
>>> arr.remove(67)
>>> arr
[13, 14, 23, 9]
```

Comment: @Amit Please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the most helpful answer. :)